# Loading Visual Studio Professional 2013 ... failed packages

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to load Visual Studio Professional 2013, but have a bunch of 'package failed' errors.
Most have to do with SQL. I recently loaded SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition (x64).
Does anyone know why I am having this difficulty?

I have a s400casus, 64-bit OS, x64-processor, Windows 8 and Java are up to date.

The messages are as follows:

> Setup Completed. However not all features installed correctly.
>
> The following packages failed:
>   MS Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)
>   MS SQL Server Compact 4.0
>   MS SQL Server System CLR Types (x64)
>   MS SQL Server 2012 Management Objects
>   MS SQL Server 2012 Management Objects (x64)

What do I need to do to fix these issues or workaround?

Comment: Try to update [SQL Server data tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx)

Comment: If you mean Update 3, I have that as well.